# How to define Enum Type Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

I have a node:

```
Database: {
  name: 'example',
  description: 'this is the example database'
  type: 'relational'
}
```

I want `type` to be an enum like:

```
DB_TYPE enum {
  relational
  document
  graph
  other
}
```

**1st Question:** How can I define this enum type so that all "database" nodes can have a `type` property that is one of these 4 values?

Should I just leave it as a string and forget about making an enum?

I considered using labels for these nodes like: `:Relational`, `:Document`.

**2nd Question:** If I should use labels, what is the cypher syntax to determine if a given `database` node is either relational, document, graph, or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. AFAIK, there is no way to define an enum property for a node. From what you described, I think you'd better use labels. If your really don't want to use labels, another alternative could be having one node per type and then connecting database nodes to these type nodes. But depending on the size of your graph, those type nodes could become super nodes with lots of relationships. I would not suggest this approach. Again to me the best solution in such usecases is to use labels.
2. The easiest would be checking labels against `labels(a)` where `a` is your node. For example:

```
MATCH (a) where 'Relational' in labels(a) OR 'Document' in labels(a) ....
```

There is also an APOC procedure `apoc.label.exists` that you can use:

```
MATCH (a) where apoc.label.exists(a, 'Relational') OR apoc.label.exists(a, 'Document')....
```

Comment: Thank you! That really helped. If I want to find out the type of a specific database node, I know I could do `MATCH` statement like: `MATCH (a:Database) WHERE ... RETURN labels(a)[1]`. Would this be the best way to do this? @NonameCurious

Comment: No problem. The problem with `labels(a)[1]` is the you'd rely on the order of the labels. You can instead do this `MATCH (a:Database) WHERE ... RETURN [x in labels(a) WHERE x <> 'Database']`. If you are sure that there are always two labels and no more, then you can return `[x in labels(a) WHERE x <> 'Database'][0]`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python with neomodel as an ORM tool, you can define your model in the following way:

```
from neomodel import StructuredNode, StringProperty

class Database(StructuredNode):
    TYPES = (
        ('RELATIONAL', 'relational'),
        ('DOCUMENT', 'document'), # ... 
    )

    name = StringProperty(unique_index=True),
    description = StringProperty(),
    type = StringProperty(choices=TYPES)
```

More info:
https://neomodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/module_documentation.html#neomodel.properties.StringProperty

https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neomodel/commit/dee7ca0b83cecf0156dc164052701ce7b8ebe14a